# Questons about the relation of PTS and DTS in H.264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, pts

Why is PTS = DTS when there is no B frame in H264?

Why is DTS not always smaller than PTS, because decoding takes time, even if PTS - DTS is a very small number?

I think the frame must be decoded before playing or is there something wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no reason to do so. PTS would always equal DTS plus some constant. So it would add data to the stream, without adding any information.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my way of describing question and answer my question . I am not very good at English.You said that "PTS would always equal DTS plus some constant".Do you mean that in fact PTS is not equal to DTS, even if PTS is equal to DTS in the expression?I don't quite understand that "So it would add data to the stream, without adding any information". Could you explain it  ,thanks again.@szatmary

Comment: I suspect you don't really understand the purpose of DTS. DTS exists ONLY because B frames exist. DTS is decode order, PTS is presentation order. Without B frames it doest matter what the decoder delay is as long as you delay the audio by the same amount. With B frames, frames can come out or order. DTS recored the order the frames must be decoded in, PTS is the order the frames must be displayed in. This order can be different.